# Web scraping : not able to scrape text and href for a given div, class and to skip the span tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to get the text and href for top news but not able to scrape it.

website : [News site](http://sandesh.com/)

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import psycopg2
import time


def checkResponse(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.content
    else:
        return None


def getTitleURL():
    url = 'http://sandesh.com/'
    response = checkResponse(url)

    if response is not None:
        html = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

    for values in html.find_all('div', class_='d-top-news-latest'):
        headline = values.find(class_='d-s-NSG-regular').text
        url = values.find(class_='d-s-NSG-regular').['href']
        print(headline + "->" + url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Getting the list of names....')
    names = getTitleURL()
    print('... done.\n')
```

Output:

```
Getting the list of names....
Corona live
મેડિકલ સ્ટાફ પર હુમલા અંગે અમિત શાહે ડોક્ટર્સ સાથે કરી ચર્ચા, સુરક્ષાની ખાતરી આપતા કરી અપીલ





Ahmedabad
ગુજરાતમાં કૂદકેને ભૂસકે વધ્યો કોરોના વાયરસનો કહેર, આજે નવા 94 કેસ નોંધાયા, જાણો કયા- કેટલા કેસ નોંધાયા





Corona live
જીવન અને મોત વચ્ચે સંઘર્ષ કરી રહ્યો છે દુનિયાનો સૌથી મોટો તાનાશાહ કિમ જોંગ! ટ્રમ્પે કહી આ વાત





Ahmedabad
અમદાવાદમાં નર્સિંગ સ્ટાફનો ગુસ્સો ફૂટ્યો, ‘અમારું કોઈ સાંભળતું નથી, અમારો કોરોના ટેસ્ટ જલદી કરાવો’





Business
ભારતીય ટેલિકોમ જગતમાં સૌથી મોટી ડીલ, ફેસબુક બની જિયોની સૌથી મોટી શેરહોલ્ડર


->http://sandesh.com/amit-shah-talk-with-ima-and-doctors-through-video-conference-on-attack/
... done.
```

I want to skip text inside the  tag and also I am able to get only 1 href. Also the headline is a list.
how do I get each title and url.

I am trying to scrape the part in red:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, At `for values in html.find_all('div', class_='d-top-news-latest')` you don't need use `for` because at DOM just have one class `d-top-news=latest`.

Second, to get the title, you can use `select('span')` because of your title into the `span` tag.

Third, you knew the headline is a list, so you need to use `for` to get each title and URL.

```
values = html.find('div', class_='d-top-news-latest')
for i in values.find_all('a', href = True):
    print(i.select('span'))
    print(i['href'])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Getting the list of names....
[<span>
Corona live
</span>]
http://sandesh.com/maharashtra-home-minister-anil-deshmukh-issue-convicts-list-of- 
palghar-case/
[<span>
Corona live
</span>]
http://sandesh.com/two-doctors-turn-black-after-treatment-of-coronavirus-in-china/
[<span>
Corona live
</span>]
http://sandesh.com/bihar-asi-gobind-singh-suspended-for-holding-home-guard-jawans- 
after-stopping-officers-car-asi/
[<span>
Ahmedabad
</span>]
http://sandesh.com/jayanti-ravi-surprise-statement-sparks-outcry-big-decision-taken- 
despite-more-patients-in-gujarat/
[<span>
Corona live
</span>]
http://sandesh.com/amit-shah-talk-with-ima-and-doctors-through-video-conference-on- 
attack/
... done.
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove the "span" part:

```
values = html.find('div', class_='d-top-news-latest')
for i in values.find_all('a', href=True):
    i.span.decompose()
    print(i.text)
    print(i['href'])
```

Output:

```
Getting the list of names....

ગુજરાતમાં કોરોનાનો કહેરઃ રાજ્યમાં આજે કોરોનાના 135 નવા કેસ, વધુ 8 લોકોનાં મોત

http://sandesh.com/gujarat-corona-update-206-new-cases-and-18-deaths/

ચીનના વૈજ્ઞાનિકોએ જ ખોલી જીનપિંગની પોલ, કોરોના વાયરસને લઈને કર્યો સનસની ખુલાસો

http://sandesh.com/chinese-scientists-claim-over-corona-virus/

શું લોકડાઉન ફરી વધારાશે? PM મોદી 27મીએ ફરી એકવાર તમામ CM સાથે કરશે ચર્ચા

http://sandesh.com/pm-modi-to-hold-video-conference-with-cms-on-april-27-lockdown- 
extension/

કોરોના વાયરસને લઈ મોટી ભવિષ્યવાણી, દુનિયાના 30 દેશો પર ઉભુ થશે ભયંકર સંકટ

http://sandesh.com/after-corona-attack-now-hunger-will-kill-many-people-in-the-world/

દેશમાં 24 કલાકમાં 1,486 કોરોનાનાં નવા કેસ, પરંતુ મળ્યા સૌથી મોટા રાહતનાં સમાચાર

http://sandesh.com/recovery-rate-increased-in-corona-patients-says-health-ministry/
... done.
```